# MySQL query very slow because of BLOB field (that can't be moved in another table)

Tags: mysql, blob

I am developping a PyQT software based on a MySql Database. The database contains some recorded electrical signals, and all the information describing these signals (sampling rate, date of recoding etc...).

To have an idea, one database contains between 10 000 and 100 000 rows, and total size is >10Gb. All these data are stored on a dedicated server. In fact, most of the data is the signal itself, which is in a BLOB field called analogsignal.signal (see below)

here is the architecture of the database : http://packages.python.org/OpenElectrophy/_images/simple_diagram1.png

I can't change it (I can add columns and indexes, but I can not move or delete existing columns).

In the software, I need to list all the analogsignal columns (id, name, channel, t_start,sampling_rate), except analogsignal.signal, which is called later via the analogsignal.id. So I'm doing the following query

> SELECT block.id, block.datetime, segment.id, analogsignal.id, analogsignal.name, analogsignal.channel, analogsignal.sampling_rate, block.fileOrigin, block.info
>
> FROM segment, block, analogsignal
>
> WHERE block.id=segment.id_block
>
> AND segment.id=analogsignal.id_segment
>
> ORDER BY analogsignal.id

The problem is, my queries are vey slow (> 10 min if the request is not in cache) because of the presence of analogsignal.signal column. If i understand correctly what's happening, the table is read line by line, including analogsignal.signal, even if the analogsignal.signal is not in the SELECT field.

Does anyone have an idea how to optimize the database or the query without moving the BLOB in an other table (which I agree would be more logical, but I do not control this point).

Thank you!

Here's the CREATE TABLE command for the AnalogSignal table (pulled/formatted from comment)

```
CREATE TABLE analogsignal 
  ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    id_segment int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    id_recordingpoint int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    name text, 
    channel int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    t_start float DEFAULT NULL, 
    sampling_rate float DEFAULT NULL, 
    signal_shape varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL, 
    signal_dtype varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL, 
    signal_blob longblob, Tag text, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    KEY ix_analogsignal_id_recordingpoint (id_recordingpoint),
    KEY ix_analogsignal_id_segment (id_segment) 
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=34798 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

**EDIT: Problem solved, here are the key points:**

-I had to add a multiple column index, type INDEX on all he SELECT fields in the analogsignal table
-The columns of 'TEXT' type blocked the use of the index. I converted these TEXT fields in VARCHAR(xx). for this I used this simple command:

> SELECT MAX(LENGTH(field_to_query)) FROM table_to_query

to check the minimal text length before conversion, to be sure that I will not loose any data

> ALTER TABLE table_to_query CHANGE field_to_query field_to_query VARCHAR(24)

I first used VARCHAR(8000), but with this setting, VARCHAR was like a TEXT field, and indexing didn't worked. No such problem with VARCHAR(24). If I'm right, the total TEXT length (all fields included) in a query must no pass 1000 bytes

Then I indexed all the columns as said above, with no size parameter in the index

Finally, using a better query structure (thank you DRapp), improved also the query.
I passed from 215s to 0.016s for the query, with no cache...

Comment: No, BLOB data is already stored by MySQL outside of the regular table storage space, so there must be another problem here. Please provide output of `EXPLAIN [your SELECT query here];` Your table probably lacks some indexes.

Comment: id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE segment ALL PRIMARY,ix_segment_id_block NULL NULL NULL 25912  
1 SIMPLE block eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 InVitro_Antoine.segment.id_block 1  
1 SIMPLE analogsignal ref ix_analogsignal_id_segment ix_analogsignal_id_segment 5 InVitro_Antoine.segment.id 1 Using where

Comment: Can you please specify the version of MySQL and the storage engine you use for the table? From the behavior you wrote I assume you use pretty old MySQL version or MyISAM for the table.

Comment: Version is 5.1.63-0ubuntu0.10.04.1, and for MyISAM I don't know

Comment: Can you do a SHOW CREATE TABLE analogsignal for me, please?

Comment: I know this is old, but can I ask how big the individual blob files were? 1MB? 10MB? 100MB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to trying to shrink your "blob" column requirements by putting the data to an external physical file and just storing the path\file name in the corresponding record, I would try the following as an alternative...

I would reverse the query and put your AnalogSignal table first as it is basis of the order by clause and reverse the query backwards to the blocks.  Also, to prevent having to read every literal row of data, if you build a compound index on all columns you want in your output, it would make a larger index, but then the query will pull the values directly from the key expression instead of from reading back to the actual rows of data.

create index KeyDataOnly on AnalogSignal ( id, id_segment, name, channel, sampling_rate )

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      block.id, 
      block.datetime, 
      segment.id, 
      analogsignal.id, 
      analogsignal.name, 
      analogsignal.channel, 
      analogsignal.sampling_rate, 
      block.fileOrigin, 
      block.info
   FROM 
      analogsignal
         JOIN Segment
            on analogsignal.id_segment = segment.id
            JOIN block
               on segment.id_block = block.id
   ORDER BY 
      analogsignal.id
```

Comment: when you say "create index KeyDataOnly on AnalogSignal ( id, id_segment, name, channel, sampling_rate )", you mean I have to index all the other columns of analogsignal first? I saw there are different way of indexing, but I don't know which one would be the best

Comment: @user1800689, correct.. one index that holds ALL the columns YOU WANT IN THE RESULT SET (or part of JOIN to segment table).  By having such an index with the columns you want returned, it does not have to go to the raw data and thus your BLOB file, it will already be fully sequential (by your "ID" to match your order by clause), and can pull the values directly from that.

Comment: Some keys are already indexed (id and id_segment). Do I have to add them again in a multiple column index?

Comment: @user1800689, If you already have one index on the ID, Id_Segment, I would just expand that index to include the other keys as well and just have as one index... this way, it does not interfere with the existing columns for other join purposes, but will now have the extra to help the query.

Comment: Ok the index is modified, I have to perform some performance test. For the "text" columns, how many characters should be indexed?

Comment: @user1800689, the entire text column of the other fields, so their full text will be included in the output.  If you only do a partial column index, then it will force back to the row for the FULL TEXT of the corresponding column and you'll end up back where you started.

Comment: The problem is that some columns are INT, others are FLOAT, others are TEXT. When I create an index with the type 'INDEX', phpmyadmin returns an error saying that I need to specify the length of the row for 'TEXT' type or rows. When I create an index with the type'FULLTEXT', phpmyadmin returns an error saying that the 'id' field can not be a FULLTEXT.

Comment: @user1800689, your diagram was unclear about data types of columns.  If some of them are based on text, and you are required to specify a length, put in whatever you would expect or allow as enough to show in the result set... if that's 30 chars or 100 chars, so be it...  If you really need the entire full text length of said fields, you might be back in the same boat as you started via the blob and going to the original full record.

Comment: Ok.There is only one field which is a Text, it's the Analogsignal.name, and it will never be longer than 100 characters. I will just have to respect this limit

Comment: Well, It's almost ok, except that the query doesn't use the Index if there is a TEXT field (even indexed). The same query without analogsignal.name take 0.03 seconds instead of 94s... If a do the EXPLAIN command, in presence of analogsignal.name, the 'key'column indicates 'null' instead of the Index. I tried FULLTEXT indexing on the 'name' column, and INDEX indexing (with chars limitation > of max legnth), but It doesn't seem to work. Do you know why?

Comment: @user1800689, Sorry, but no, don't know why.  I guess I would just remove the "text" column element from the index and try to run the query as presented.

Comment: If I do this, it's ok, the queries are fast now. But I need the text informations of this column. Can I force MySQL to use the FULLTEXT index?

Comment: @user1800689, why do you care about the full text index (unless you want to apply a WHERE clause that criteria), it appears it has to go to the row anyhow to get the full "name" context for the query per the index with the column not liking it.

Comment: Yes, there can be a WHERE clause on this criteria in my software. analogsignal.name indicates the channel name used. Usually it is 'Vm' or 'Im' in my recordings. I just don't understand why whith all other analogsignal (channel, id, sampling_rate) indexing works, but doesn't work anymore if analogsignal.name is in SELECT. For information, I just tried to convert analogsignal.name from TEXT to VARCHAR, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: ok problem solved, see edit in the initial post! Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot delete the BLOB column, do you have to fill it? You could add a column for storing the path/to/filename of your signal and then put all your signal files in the appropriate directory(s). Once that's done, set your BLOB field values to null.

It's probably breaking the spirit of the restrictions you're under.  But *arbitrary* restrictions often need to be circumvented.

Comment: An other software load the RAW data in the database, and this software is necessary for different kind of analysis. So I do not control the importation of the data, and I must keep the original structure and BLOB field. I can only complete the database.

Comment: @user1800689: ok, so what if you make a child table that contains only the data you need?  You can put a trigger on the main table such that the data you need is automatically added to your child table. Then use the child table for the query.

Comment: Do you mean like a mirror of the analogsignal table, with all columns except analogsignal.signal (the BLOB)?

Comment: As we use an other software based on the same database (which is slow for the same reasons), if I could find a way to improve the original database itself, it would be better. However, if I can't, I will try this child table solution!

Answer (score 1):

So according the comments I'm sure your problem is caused by the MyISAM storage engine and its behavior on storing the data. toxicate20 is right. The MySQL has to skip through those big blobs anyway which is not effective. You can change the storage engine for InnoDB which will help a lot in this problem. Will only read the blob data if you explicitly ask for it in the SELECT ... part.

```
ALTER TABLE analogsignal ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This will take a while but helps a lot in performance. You can read more about InnoDB file formats here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-row-format-antelope.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-row-format-dynamic.html

Disclaimer: If you use fulltext search (MATCH ... AGAINST http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-search.html) on any of the columns in the table you cannot change it to InnoDB.

Comment: I saw this in my research, but I also saw that InnoDB files are harder to save. We have a weekly automated saving of all the db files (I am not the only user), done by copying the files.

Comment: What do you mean copying the files? Hot copy of the myisam MY[DI] and .frm files? In a way you're right it's a bit harder with InnoDB as you have tablespace(s) and you have to keep its integrity. 

But you should be aware that MyISAM is not ACID and hot copy myisam files can occur data loss especially if do it without "flush tables with read lock".

Comment: One other thing. Take a look on XtraBackup from Percona which can do hot copy of InnoDB files in a way that it ensures data consistency.

Answer (score 0):

As the analog signal column is pretty large the query will take a long time because it has to skip (or jump over them if you see it metaphorically) them when doing a select query. What I would do is the following: Instead of having a blob in the database, generate binary files via

```
$fh = fopen("analogfile.spec", 'w') or die("can't open file");
$data = $yourAnalogDataFromSomewhere;
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);
```

The filename would be given by the ID of the column for example. Instead of the blob you would just add the filepath within your server directory structure.

This way your query will run very fast as it does not have to skip the big chunks of data in the blob column.

Comment: Did you see that the database layout can not be modified (he stated: (I can add columns and indexes, but I can not move or delete existing columns))

Comment: @toxicate20: What you wrote with the jumping is only true if the table is MyISAM. InnoDB stores the blob data in a separate page in the tablespace. Depends on the row format it only stores a pointer (Barracuda) or a the first 768 bytes of the blob and a pointer for the rest (Antelope).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-row-format-antelope.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-row-format-dynamic.html